# Having issues with pointers and AVL tree in C++ code

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, avl-tree

I just started learning about AVL trees in my data structures and algorithms class. I found code on Geeks for Geeks that inserts a new node into the tree  and balances it. The code is shown below.

```
// C++ program to insert a node in AVL tree 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
// An AVL tree node 
class Node 
{ 
    public:
    int key; 
    Node *left; 
    Node *right; 
    int height; 
}; 
 
// A utility function to get maximum
// of two integers 
int max(int a, int b); 
 
// A utility function to get the 
// height of the tree 
int height(Node *N) 
{ 
    if (N == NULL) 
        return 0; 
    return N->height; 
} 
 
// A utility function to get maximum
// of two integers 
int max(int a, int b) 
{ 
    return (a > b)? a : b; 
} 
 
/* Helper function that allocates a 
   new node with the given key and 
   NULL left and right pointers. */
Node* newNode(int key) 
{ 
    Node* node = new Node();
    node->key = key; 
    node->left = NULL; 
    node->right = NULL; 
    node->height = 1; // new node is initially
                      // added at leaf 
    return(node); 
} 
 
// A utility function to right
// rotate subtree rooted with y 
// See the diagram given above. 
Node *rightRotate(Node *y) 
{ 
    Node *x = y->left; 
    Node *T2 = x->right; 
 
    // Perform rotation 
    x->right = y; 
    y->left = T2; 
 
    // Update heights 
    y->height = max(height(y->left),
                    height(y->right)) + 1; 
    x->height = max(height(x->left),
                    height(x->right)) + 1; 
 
    // Return new root 
    return x; 
} 
 
// A utility function to left 
// rotate subtree rooted with x 
// See the diagram given above. 
Node *leftRotate(Node *x) 
{ 
    Node *y = x->right; 
    Node *T2 = y->left; 
 
    // Perform rotation 
    y->left = x; 
    x->right = T2; 
 
    // Update heights 
    x->height = max(height(x->left),    
                    height(x->right)) + 1; 
    y->height = max(height(y->left), 
                    height(y->right)) + 1; 
 
    // Return new root 
    return y; 
} 
 
// Get Balance factor of node N 
int getBalance(Node *N) 
{ 
    if (N == NULL) 
        return 0; 
    return height(N->left) - height(N->right); 
} 
 
// Recursive function to insert a key
// in the subtree rooted with node and
// returns the new root of the subtree. 
Node* insert(Node* node, int key) 
{ 
    /* 1. Perform the normal BST insertion */
    if (node == NULL) 
        return(newNode(key)); 
 
    if (key < node->key) 
        node->left = insert(node->left, key); 
    else if (key > node->key) 
        node->right = insert(node->right, key); 
    else // Equal keys are not allowed in BST 
        return node; 
 
    /* 2. Update height of this ancestor node */
    node->height = 1 + max(height(node->left), 
                        height(node->right)); 
 
    /* 3. Get the balance factor of this ancestor 
        node to check whether this node became 
        unbalanced */
    int balance = getBalance(node); 
 
    // If this node becomes unbalanced, then 
    // there are 4 cases 
 
    // Left Left Case 
    if (balance > 1 && key < node->left->key) 
        return rightRotate(node); 
 
    // Right Right Case 
    if (balance < -1 && key > node->right->key) 
        return leftRotate(node); 
 
    // Left Right Case 
    if (balance > 1 && key > node->left->key) 
    { 
        node->left = leftRotate(node->left); 
        return rightRotate(node); 
    } 
 
    // Right Left Case 
    if (balance < -1 && key < node->right->key) 
    { 
        node->right = rightRotate(node->right); 
        return leftRotate(node); 
    } 
 
    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node; 
} 
 
// A utility function to print preorder 
// traversal of the tree. 
// The function also prints height 
// of every node 
void preOrder(Node *root) 
{ 
    if(root != NULL) 
    { 
        cout << root->key << " "; 
        preOrder(root->left); 
        preOrder(root->right); 
    } 
} 
 
// Driver Code
int main() 
{ 
    Node *root = NULL; 
     
    /* Constructing tree given in 
    the above figure */
    root = insert(root, 10); 
    root = insert(root, 20); 
    root = insert(root, 30); 
    root = insert(root, 40); 
    root = insert(root, 50); 
    root = insert(root, 25); 
     
    /* The constructed AVL Tree would be 
                30 
            / \ 
            20 40 
            / \ \ 
        10 25 50 
    */
    cout << "\n\n" << "Preorder traversal of the "
            "constructed AVL tree is \n"; 
    preOrder(root); 
    cout << "\n\n";
     
    return 0; 
} 
 
// This code is contributed by
// rathbhupendra
```

I understand how the code works pretty ok (at least I think I do). I edited the code a little to try a slightly different approach. For the leftRotate and rightRotate functions, originially, they take a pointer as a parameter and return the rotated pointer ("Node *leftRotate(Node *x)"). I tried to change that by instead having a pass by reference pointer parameter and return type void ("void leftRotate(Node*& x)"). The code is shown below (I added the comment "//CHANGED" next to everywhere I changed from the original code).

```
// C++ program to insert a node in AVL tree 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
// An AVL tree node 
class Node 
{ 
    public:
    int key; 
    Node *left; 
    Node *right; 
    int height; 
}; 
 
// A utility function to get maximum
// of two integers 
int max(int a, int b); 
 
// A utility function to get the 
// height of the tree 
int height(Node *N) 
{ 
    if (N == NULL) 
        return 0; 
    return N->height; 
} 
 
// A utility function to get maximum
// of two integers 
int max(int a, int b) 
{ 
    return (a > b)? a : b; 
} 
 
/* Helper function that allocates a 
   new node with the given key and 
   NULL left and right pointers. */
Node* newNode(int key) 
{ 
    Node* node = new Node();
    node->key = key; 
    node->left = NULL; 
    node->right = NULL; 
    node->height = 1; // new node is initially
                      // added at leaf 
    return(node); 
} 
 
// A utility function to right
// rotate subtree rooted with y 
// See the diagram given above. 
void rightRotate(Node*& y) //CHANGED
{ 
    Node *x = y->left; 
    Node *T2 = x->right; 
 
    // Perform rotation 
    x->right = y; 
    y->left = T2; 
 
    // Update heights 
    y->height = max(height(y->left),
                    height(y->right)) + 1; 
    x->height = max(height(x->left),
                    height(x->right)) + 1; 
 
    // Return new root 
    //return x; //CHANGED
} 
 
// A utility function to left 
// rotate subtree rooted with x 
// See the diagram given above. 
void leftRotate(Node*& x) //CHANGED
{ 
    Node *y = x->right; 
    Node *T2 = y->left; 
 
    // Perform rotation 
    y->left = x; 
    x->right = T2; 
 
    // Update heights 
    x->height = max(height(x->left),    
                    height(x->right)) + 1; 
    y->height = max(height(y->left), 
                    height(y->right)) + 1; 
 
    // Return new root 
    //return y; //CHANGED
} 
 
// Get Balance factor of node N 
int getBalance(Node *N) 
{ 
    if (N == NULL) 
        return 0; 
    return height(N->left) - height(N->right); 
} 
 
// Recursive function to insert a key
// in the subtree rooted with node and
// returns the new root of the subtree. 
Node* insert(Node* node, int key) 
{ 
    /* 1. Perform the normal BST insertion */
    if (node == NULL) 
        return(newNode(key)); 
 
    if (key < node->key) 
        node->left = insert(node->left, key); 
    else if (key > node->key) 
        node->right = insert(node->right, key); 
    else // Equal keys are not allowed in BST 
        return node; 
 
    /* 2. Update height of this ancestor node */
    node->height = 1 + max(height(node->left), 
                        height(node->right)); 
 
    /* 3. Get the balance factor of this ancestor 
        node to check whether this node became 
        unbalanced */
    int balance = getBalance(node); 
 
    // If this node becomes unbalanced, then 
    // there are 4 cases 
 
    // Left Left Case 
    if (balance > 1 && key < node->left->key) 
        rightRotate(node); //CHANGED
 
    // Right Right Case 
    if (balance < -1 && key > node->right->key) 
        leftRotate(node); //CHANGED
 
    // Left Right Case 
    if (balance > 1 && key > node->left->key) 
    { 
        leftRotate(node->left); //CHANGED
        rightRotate(node); //CHANGED
    } 
 
    // Right Left Case 
    if (balance < -1 && key < node->right->key) 
    { 
        rightRotate(node->right); //CHANGED
        leftRotate(node); //CHANGED
    } 
 
    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node; 
} 
 
// A utility function to print preorder 
// traversal of the tree. 
// The function also prints height 
// of every node 
void preOrder(Node *root) 
{ 
    if(root != NULL) 
    { 
        cout << root->key << " "; 
        preOrder(root->left); 
        preOrder(root->right); 
    } 
} 
 
// Driver Code
int main() 
{ 
    Node *root = NULL; 
     
    /* Constructing tree given in 
    the above figure */
    root = insert(root, 10); 
    root = insert(root, 20); 
    root = insert(root, 30); 
    root = insert(root, 40); 
    root = insert(root, 50); 
    root = insert(root, 25); 
     
    /* The constructed AVL Tree would be 
                30 
            / \ 
            20 40 
            / \ \ 
        10 25 50 
    */
    cout << "\n\n" << "Preorder traversal of the "
            "constructed AVL tree is \n"; 
    preOrder(root); 
    cout << "\n\n";
     
    return 0; 
} 
 
// This code is contributed by
// rathbhupendra
```

My logic for doing this is that instead of returning the rotated pointer, I can just pass the pointer by reference, allowing the function to do the rotation to the pointer itself instead of a copy of the pointer. However, when I run this code, I get either segmentation fault or just no output (on GeeksforGeeks coding environment its segmentation fault and on VS code its just no output). Is there something that I am also supposed to change, or am I just doing this wrong. I've passed pointers by reference like this before in previous code and they have all worked as expected, so I don't understand why this wouldn't work. Any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the original and the modified version of one snippet of code, and [explain everything that's happening here to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging):

```
// Right Right Case 
if (balance < -1 && key > node->right->key) 
    return leftRotate(node);
```

Before, `leftRotate` was called to rotate `node`, and the rotated `node` *gets returned from this function* (`node` is a parameter to this function). This is how you will describe what's happening here to your rubber duck.

And now, let's try explaining the modified version of this code to your rubber duck:

```
// Right Right Case 
if (balance < -1 && key > node->right->key) 
    leftRotate(node); //CHANGED
```

You see, Mr. Rubber Duck, `leftRotate` gets called, and it modifies the parameter that gets passed by reference with what the original version of `leftRotate`() returned, and that's it!

Your rubber duck will now point out your problem and say: "Fine! But you should, right about now, notice one glaring difference: the value that `leftRotate`() originally returned itself, which is now the new `node`, ***no longer gets `return`ed from this function***. The "CHANGED" version of the code is not logically equivalent to the original version!"

See how helpful your rubber duck was? This same logical error occurs multiple times in the changed version, referencing the changed `leftRotate` and `rightRotate`.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand. How are they not logically equivalent. In those functions, no new memory was allocated so any pointer declared and assigned points to the same address. So,  "Node *x = y->left;" for example, this makes x point to the same address as "y->left", so by changing "x->right', I am essentially changing "y->left->right", aren't I?

Comment: This has nothing to do, whatsoever, with anything pointing to anything else. In the original version, you `return` from the function. In the modified version you ***DO NOT***. Try adding `return`s to various functions, in random places (or remove some existing ones), and see if things continue to work exactly as they were before. They won't be.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I see what your saying. In my version I just changed the `y` pointer (or `x`) but the new root still has to be returned. I changed it back to returning the new node pointer, but if I leave it the pass by reference parameter I do not get the right output (I changed it from `void rightRotate(Node*& y) ` to `Node* rightRotate(Node*& y) `). The output is supposed to be: "Preorder traversal of the constructed AVL tree is 
30 20 10 25 40 50". Instead I get: "Preorder traversal of the constructed AVL tree is
40 30 25 50" Do you know why this is?

Comment: This must be due to another logical differences between the two versions. You just have to find them. Since you've already changed the shown code even more, it's not possible for anyone to be to make any statement regarding some different version of code that's not even shown. Perhaps you made some kind of a typo or mistake, making your additional fixes, this cannot be stated for certain.

Comment: ahh ok. Well, thank you for all your help. I'll post another question with the new code.